# Summing one value, conditionally on another value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am using VS.NET 2008 C#. I have created a report using Crystal Reports. In this report I have a text field, Container Quantity (ContQty), and another text field, Container Type (ContType).

There are 4 different values for ContType, mainly "20 Foot Normal", "40 Foot Normal", "40 Foot High Cube" and "By Air".

For a certain group I would like to sum the ContQty based on the ContType. For instance, if one grouping has 5 rows of data with 2 x 20 Foot Normal and 3 x 40 Foot High Cube containers, in the grouping total it should show 2 x 20 Foot Containers and 3 x 40 Foot Containers.

Now using the below formula I managed to get it to display the correct figures if all the container types are similar in each grouping.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;

NumberVar Quantity := 0;

StringVar ContType := "";

ContType := {ContType database field};

IF ContType = "20 Foot Normal" OR ContType = "By Air"

THEN Quantity := SUM({@ConvertContQtyToNumber}, {Group Name})

ELSE Quantity := 0;

Quantity;
```

Problem is if you have different ContType's it sums all the ContQty's, depending on the last ContType, and displays the total sum of all the ContType's for that grouping as the total number of containers for the last ContType. So if the last ContType is 40 Foot High Cube using the above example, the total would be 5 x 40 Foot Containers.

How do I get it to display the correct results. I have 2 formulas, for the 20 and 40 Foot containers. The above one is just for the 20 Foot Containers.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

1. Create four formulas, one for each of the values for ContType, defined like this:

   ```
   if ContType = "20 Foot Normal" then ContQty else 0
   ```

   Then you can use `Sum({@ContQty_20FootNormal}, {Group Name})` in your summary formula.
2. Add another grouping level – for `ContType` – and display the total in the header or footer of the new group.

Comment: Thanks, that worked... Had tried this earlier but it kept giving me this formula field cannot be summed error. Thanks

Comment: How does one go about closing the question? Thanks once again

Comment: Maybe you'd tried `ContType = "20 Foot Normal"`, which is a boolean, and can't be summed? Anyway, yes, click the check mark to accept the answer, and vote it up if you like.